# iPad slidable right hand side

Tags: xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

How did they do it? Look at these images:

[image]

[image]

As you can see you can slide the right panel to the left and back. Is that UISplitViewController?

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely a custom view/controller. The stock split view is what it is. Although I think Matt Gammell cooked up a replacement split view that let's you drag the split around, it only changes the proportional size or visibility of your two views. It would take some additional customization to give it this kind of look and feel. I don't have the URL handy though, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this, but you can check this open source class called [IIViewDeckController available in github](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/) - it's exactly what you need. You can set a right and a left view, add shadows, customize tap or slide interactivity.

It contains a example project so you can understand how to program all properties.